# What could cause a laptop's keyboard to stop functioning?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Every now and then my laptop's keyboard stops functioning. It fails to register keystrokes in the conventional way - I am for example unable to type, and the Windows key doesn't work either. But it does register keystrokes: pressing any key for example brings up the options menu in Google Chrome. The problem is solved by restarting the computer.

What could be causing the problem in the first place? The obvious answer is an external object is holding down a key on the keyboard, but the keyboard is clear, and if a physical reason is the cause restarting the computer shouldn't affect it.

Comment: Does the issue occur with an external keyboard plugged in? If so, it would confirm the issue is in software (driver, OS, etc.) rather than with the keyboard, wiring or controller.

Comment: It seems like the issue is caused by a program ... I was able to get it to happen three consecutive times by starting up the program, although it doesn't happen all the time, and sometimes the program works fine.